# Where can I find datasets of running Waveshare 99001 Track Map?

Tags: raspberry-pi

I'm trying to build autonomous-driving system on my raspberrypi - piracer with `Rasbian 64bit OS` and `Raspberry Pi 4 Model B Rev 1.5`.
I want the car running on the Waveshare 99001 Track Map.

First, I tried to use `donkeycar`, but I've failed because my system cannot run `picamera` and it cannot be fixed (as I know, I check in this [conversation](https://github.com/raspberrypi/userland/issues/688))

Now I'm looking for datasets to train CNN models. I want to get right steering angle, but I have no clue for where can I get these dataset or something. How can I solve this problem?